# How to avoid using Math.Random() on bitaddress.org on Iceweasel 20

Tags: javascript, node.js, bitcoin, cryptocurrency, iceweasel

I'm trying to generate wallet addresses securely. I have an older airgapped computer than has no networking hardware on it. I booted a live USB and opened the source files for bitaddress.org in Iceweasel 20. It appears to work and generate addresses, but if I open the console it displays:

"WARNING:

A secure random number generator was not found.

Using Math.Random(), which is NOT cryptographically strong!"

Looking through the code, it appears to me that bitaddress.org uses either node.js crypto.randomBytes() or window.crypto.getRandomValues(). Iceweasel 20 does not have window.crypto.getRandomValues() implimented, and I'm not sure how to include Node.js on an airgapped computer.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you thought about using Bitcoin Core to generate addresses securely? It does this very nicely on an airgapped computer - you could boot into Tails and keep Bitcoin Core binaries on a persistent partition on the USB drive, which is easy to set up with Tails.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I use coinflips personally, but I wanted to test the security of bitaddress.org.